# Invalid shape when i train_test_split

Tags: python, train-test-split

I am getting shape error when I `train_test_split` the data
the code are follows

```
y = data['Cover_type']
X = data.drop('Cover_Type',axis=1)
```

when I train_test_split it doesn't give me error but when i fit the `GradientBoostingRegressor` and find the accuracy it give me shape error of

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10584, 4536]
```

enter code here
`from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split       from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score X_train,y_train,X_valid,y_valid =  train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)`

Comment: Please include actual code that caused the error

Comment: 'code' gb = GradientBoostingRegressor()
gb.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = gb.predict(X_valid)
acc_score = accuracy_score(y_valid,y_pred)
print(acc_score)

Comment: after this code it gives me value error of invalid shape

Comment: add all the code to the question, this is still very incomplete. preferably print shapes along the way and include these print outputs too. only this way can we track down exactly where the problem occurs

Comment: as it defined by error the shape of X_train and y_train is different, I have no idea why this happen as both  are from the same data